# which wallet supports access list(eip-2930)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethers.js, eip

I am trying to use `Access List` feature - [Link here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2930)

I am using also `ethers.js`..

It seems like that `ethers.js` supports passing `access list`, but Metamask doesn't yet support this feature.

do you know any dapp wallet that supports this ?

Comment: Can you please share an example of a settled transaction using Ethers.js using EIP-2930?

Answer (score 1):

Dapper Legacy Wallet does support it but the wallet does not have great reviews online so be careful.